# StackExchage data explorer gets around restrictions

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign

I believe [data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) is enabling users to get around restrictions, as with a simple query, users with less than 1000 rep can get vote counts(the ones unlocked by Trusted User), (see [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntu/query/466/most-controversial-posts-on-the-site)), as well as many kinds of votes or possibly even flags(line 4 on [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntu/query/70682/close-votes-cast-by-a-user), or even that number changed to get scarier vote statistics). I believe that the system should be revised denying access to sensitive data to users that don't have sufficient rep on the site they are looking at.

Comment: The only thing on the site that is 'private' is the stuff that moderators see, which is both fairly specific and governed by an NDA.

Comment: Yes. Although the stuff I'm talking about isn't private, it still is a waste of reputation tracking code to make it available on StackExchange data explorer.

Comment: It's all about ease of access. This isn't a problem.

Comment: I'll accept the "No" answer when I can, in two days.

Comment: The API also allows access to this information (up/down vote counts).

Comment: It's not that it would be difficult to lock down. It's that there is no compelling reason to lock it down. Being able to display up and down votes counts is a *feature* that you get access to with a certain amount of reputation. The *feature* is what's rep-dependent, not the information that the feature is one way to access. Thought of that way, this is not really getting past new user restrictions at all.

Comment: @jrg Can you tag this [meta-tag:status-bydesign]?

Comment: @EliahKagan: Ah... but what about the UserScripts that actually do add this feature?

Comment: Having read some MSO posts(I don't have links, sorry), it looks like everything that isn't blocked at the 10K or mod level is visible. The reason vote counts are blocked below 1000 rep is because it is a complex `COUNT(........` query and is not stored in the post table, and as such, is very heavy on the database servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No

We should allow users to get past new user restrictions.